# Right Click Paste Event for Character Counter

Tags: jquery, html

I've created a character counter and it works fine, including detecting the control-v paste and adjusting the counter accordingly, but I can't get it to detect and adjust for the right-click paste.  When I right click and paste in the text box the counter doesn't detect it automatically, but when you space over or add new input it adjusts accordingly.  I've read over several posts and tried what they suggested by adding 'paste' as an attribute with my 'keyup' attribute but not much luck.

Here is the fiddle link and code (in case there's an issue with the link):

http://jsfiddle.net/NewJSDeveloper/yg45sfus/3/

```
<div id="testDiv">
  <label for="usAddressInput" id="usAddressLabel" style="margin-right:35px">Address</label>
  <div>
    <input  id="USAddressInput" type="text"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label id="newlabel">New Label</label>
   </div>
</div>

$('#USAddressInput').on('keyup', function() {
  var cs = 13 - $(this).val().length;
  $("#counter").html("(" + cs + " chars)");
});

$('#USAddressInput').attr('maxlength', '13');

var counter = "<span id=\"counter\" style=\"font-style:italic;\">(13 chars)</span>";
$('#usAddressLabel').after(counter);
```

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `input` event too :

```
$('#USAddressInput').on('keyup input', function() {
    var cs = 13 - $(this).val().length;
    $("#counter").html("(" + cs + " chars)");
});
```

This is working on Chrome ([see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg45sfus/6/))

Answer (score 0):

Change the event trigger to this.

```
$('#USAddressInput').bind('input propertychange', function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yg45sfus/7/